# Usage of skeleton in a search context

Tags: response-time, loading, preloader

I was wondering if it was a good practice to use a skeleton in a context of search and filtering or is it better to only use it when the page is loading and use a spinner on the list while filtering or searching?

As a result, I can have 1 item minimum or more than 20.

[image: search & filter skeleton]

Comment: How long does it take to get the results?

Comment: Currently, It is not very performant, I would say around 2 to 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The intent of a skeleton page is to shorten *perceived* loading time. If your filtering requires a re-loading of the page data, then, sure, it could make sense to use it there.

That said, and this is just my opinion so take it for what it is: I'm not convinced skeleton pages have much staying power to them in terms of them accomplishing what they were originally designed to do. People pretty much now know it's just a fake layout to make the page *appear* to load faster. And more recent studies I've seen haven't convinced me otherwise. :)

Comment: "And more recent studies I've seen haven't convinced me otherwise"

Could you provide sources, please?